# "are disposed" or "were disposed"

Tags: tenses, past-tense

Have you ever wondered where certain substances **are** contained inside laboratories and where these laboratory wastes **are** disposed?

or

Have you ever wondered where certain substances **were** contained inside laboratories and where these laboratory wastes **were** disposed?

Please help

Comment: Is all of disposal in the past or does it continue?

Comment: If you make the clause active instead of passive, you can more clearly see that you need the present tense: *Have you ever wondered where scientists **contain** substances inside laboratories and where they **dispose** these laboratory wastes?* (Use *are* in your sentence.)

Comment: It's the same difference as exists between "What _did_ the Ancient Greeks do with their kitchen waste?" and "What _do_ McDonalds do with their kitchen waste?" The Ancient Greeks are long gone but McDonalds are still with us.